# Rails 4 "undefined method `accessor'" after migration

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

My Rails 4.1.5 app is on Ruby 2.1 and using postgresql with hstore for store_accessor. Starting with a new database:

```
rake db:migrate; rake db:seed
```

...everything works fine.

Rollback and forward again and here's where the problem starts:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0; rake db:migrate; rake db:seed
```

The model reports "undefined method accessor" if I try to access any of the 'properties' it.

```
undefined method `accessor' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::OID::Identity:0xyaddayadda>
```

The model is using store_accessor with postrgesql's hstore. The model is defined like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  store_accessor :properties, :color, :material, :brand
  ...
end
```

And the migration is defined like this:

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension "hstore"
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.hstore      :properties

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

To make the problem go away I can do completely blast away the db before recreating it:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0; rake db:drop:all; rake db:create; rake db:migrate; rake db:seed
```

Doing so means stopping and restarting the test and dev environments each time, which is a hassle.

I've tried adding another migration that enables/disables hstore:

```
class AddHstore < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    enable_extension :hstore
  end
  def down
    disable_extension :hstore
  end
end
```

This runs before the Foo migration.

I suspect this is a problem with the posgresql ActiveRecord connector. It's possible I'm using this wrong so I want to bounce it off you guys.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in ActiveRecord and I've logged and issue in github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16971. I'll update this question when we have a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused because of the field which we are putting as store_accessor is not present under the database. running migration making sure that field exists, that solves error for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was dockerizing my non-docker rails app which was working just fine when I connected with Postgres 14. In docker I used Postgres 15's image and this problem occurred. Because I was using code like below:

```rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  store_accessor :properties, :color, :material, :brand
  ...
end
```

When I switched back to Postgres 14, them the problem was gone

```
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=yourpassword
```